# EF DbContext from Database vs. EF power tools reverse engineer from database. What is difference ?

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-power-tools

I am using an existing database and my normal method is to add a new Entity Data Model and point it to the existing database. If I was to use the EF power tools and reverse engineer to make it 'code first' style what is the advantage of this ?

Both are classes that inherit from DbContext right ? So can someone explain to me what an advantage might be working with the code base over time if I was to use the EF power tools reverse engineer tool instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code First to an existing database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620) generates your model (at runtime) from your C# classes. [Database First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878) stores the model inside of an .edmx file and generates your classes (at design time).

The video [Entity Framework Development Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj590134) gives a good overview. Ultimately, it comes down to whether you want to maintain your model using a designer surface or using C# classes.

It is also worth mentioning that, if you want to use [Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621), you have to use Code First since it currently doesn't work with Database First.

Comment: So as far as the code using either one is it exactly the same?  In my case I have a DB person that makes changes on occasion to the DB so I create a new Entity Data Model file when he does and point to the updated db... So in this case Code first to an existing DB would not make sense since after the conversion the changes are coming from the DB and not from code. Yes?

Comment: @punkouter Correct, the code using the DbContext and entities is exactly the same either way. You could re-reverse engineer after the database is changed, but I think you're right, Database First sounds like it fits your needs just fine so there is no compelling reason to switch.